# how to fix gst/gst.h not found on Visual studio code running on UBUNTU

Tags: visual-studio-code, gcc, ubuntu-18.04, vscode-debugger, gstreamer-1.0

On the terminal we can use 'pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0' along with gcc <file.c> -o  to complile the gstreamer application and avoid gst/gst.h not found error.
I am using ubuntu 18.04 to run the test application. I use VS Code remote ssh to edit the code on Ubuntu. But I am not able to build or debug the code because of this error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWEO6.png)

Is there a way to tell VS code to compile with this pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 flag.
Or is there a way to tell gcc to automatically look for gst.h in gstreamer libraries.

I am new to this, I enjoy using VS Code, and dont want to switch back and froth from the terminal.

Comment: `gst.h` : Search a package name with 'apt-file search' , or on-line https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&searchon=contents&keywords=gst.h ........ `sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-dev`

Answer (score 1):

To solve editor include error, add this to your Include path:

```
${workspaceFolder}/*
/usr/include/gstreamer-1.0/*
```

It works for current latest Visual Code (version 1.71.2). Pay attention to **one asterisk character only**

To solve compilation error, add this for your **task.json**:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc-9 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/gcc-9",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                **"`pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`"**
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```